# jQuery Lava Lamp Navigation Problem in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've implemented a lava lamp style navigation menu (from [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-lava-lamp-style-navigation-menu/)) to work with my WordpPress blog's navigation menu. This function needs to select an id or class for the navigation menu link it is supposed to hover over. I set this up in the function's code to select `<li class="current_page_item">`, which is a class applied by WordPress to the navigation list element that corresponds to the page you're on.

The problem is that when you're on a post permalink page, category page, or on an older page, the lava lamp function doesn't work because none of the navigation list items have the `current_page_item` class since they're not pages that are reached by the navigation menu.

On these pages (any page not on the nav menu), I just want the slider to default to the "home" link.

The simplest solution I could think of would be to write a piece of javascript & jQuery that does the following before I run the lava lamp function: `if no <li> has class="current_page_item", then addclass "current_page_item" to first <li>` I just don't know enough JS or jQuery to write this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't!

Nahhh just kidding, do it this way,

```
$(function(){
   var $menu = $('ul#menu');

   // look for <li class="current_page_item"> , .length would return greater than zero if there is matched element. 
   if (! $menu.find('.current_page_item').length ) {
      // add the class on the first child if no matched...
      $menu.children('li:first-child').addClass('current_page_item');
   }

});
```

Comment: This code works like it's supposed to but the problem is that I'm still getting the same error from the beginning: currentPageItem.position() is null
[Break on this error] left : currentPageItem.position().left I guess it's not doing it fast enough to the DOM before the lava lamp function fires.

Comment: I put a 150ms setTimeout on the lava lamp function so now it works! Thanks!